# How to remove UIBarButtonItem Gloss effect?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa, uibarbuttonitem

I'm trying to remove glossy effect of UIBarButtonItem on my toolbar/navigationItem.

I read some about subclassing it and implement **initWithCustomView** but I don't know how to use it to render the button without the glossy (glass) effect.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

So you create a button in IB or code, then that becomes the custom view. If you look in the class reference for UIBarButtonItem and initWithCustomView, you will see Apple has listed 5 sample projects that use that technique - so you can see what they did and how it looks.

Comment: thank you David, yes I've read the documentation but I just had found image driven buttons.actually I like to keep the button look and feel just without the gloss effect. Is there some way to render it that way?

Comment: Well, do a simple test - won't take but a few minutes. Create a button in IB, add it as the custom view. The UIBarButtonItem does funky stuff with the action messages as I recall - not sure you can bypass it (I seem to recall it only gives you value changed or something, as it intercepts the button action messages. Sigh - just not sure now. In any case try making several button types and putting them in the UIBarButton and see what happens. You can always create a UIView, paint it background some color, then add a button to that too. You have lots of ways to customize.

Comment: Thank you so much David for your information, I will try them tonight. :)